# Java How to launch myapp by opening an image?

Tags: java, android, file, intentfilter

I'm working on an image editor app and I want to have my app being in the 'Open With ...' list when the user clicks on an image from file manager or ... (Like how 'Photo Editor' app did) :

[Click to see the example (Edited)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OQy1E.png)

And the problem is that I don't know how to do such a thing.

I have researched in youtube and I found that it's about the `intent filter` in the `Manifest.xml` file.

I already tried adding some `<action/>` to my intent filter by random but it  didn't worked.

Comment: Try to read about Implicit intent, read [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters)

Comment: if you think my answer will help futures devs then you can upvote it 

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go to the `Manifest` file and search for your `LAUNCHER` activity for example `SplashActivity`

like this

```
  <activity
    android:name=".SplashActivity"
    android:exported="true">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
      //this below code help you to get image from other apps if shared
     <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
    </intent-filter>

</activity>
```

And To get that data in your **SplashActivity** do this :

```
 Intent intent = getIntent();
 String action = intent.getAction();
 String type = intent.getType();
 //this will check that you are getting only image type not text
 boolean isImage = Intent.ACTION_SEND.equals(action) && "image/*".equals(type);

if(getIntent().getData() != null && isImage){
 // here you got the data and you can send this data or uri 
 // to your image editor activity
 Uri imageUri = intent.getData();
}
```

And you can send that image to the next activity by doing this

you can store the URI as a string

```
Intent nextIntent = new Intent(this, EditorActivity.java);
nextIntent.putExtra("imageUri", imageUri.toString());
startActivity(nextIntent)
```

and then just convert the string back to URI like this in your (**EditorActivity**)

```
Uri myUri = Uri.parse(getIntent().getStringExtra("imageUri"));
```